# Learn ring theory more fun

Tags: abstract-algebra, applied-mathematics

I asked this question at ['mathoverflow'](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460493/the-game-related-to-ring-theory). However, the character of this question does not match mathoverflow, so I am asking this question again on this site.

**Motivation:**

Among abstract algebra, I am interested in ring theory, which is closely related to algebraic geometry. And among them, I am very interested in ring of integers, which is familiar because it is related to number theory and interested in Ideal theory, which Dedekind first formalized in detail. Among various ideals, the ones of particular interest are ‘maximal ideal’ and ‘prime ideal’.

I saw [the book "Concepts of Modern Mathematics" by Ian Stewart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486284247). In this book, I saw the game, **'solitaire game'**. the game's rule is like this below contents.

> The game of solitaire as you probably know, is played on a board with holes in the pattern

[image]

> At the start, each hole except the centre contains a peg. The player may jump any peg over another horizontally or vertically adjacent peg into an empty hole, removing the peg jumped over. Diagonal moves are not allowed. The aim is to remove all pegs but one. Usually, it is required that the last peg should end up in the centre. Anyone playing the game will observe, if he plays it enough, that although the final peg need not end up in the centre, it does not seem possible to make it finish anywhere. There is a limited number of final positions.

**We shall ask:** In what positions is it possible for the last peg to be? And we shall answer it by a method due to de Bruijn, using a certain field with 4 elements.

This book says that this game is a game that utilizes field theory. At this point, I became curious about whether there were any games that utilized ring theory.

**Why this game is related to field theory?**

We shall answer it by a method due to de Bruijn, using a certain field with 4 elements. The elements will be $0,1$, $p$, and $q$: and addition and multiplications are defined by the tables

[image]

We observe that the equation $p^2+p+1=0$ holds.(This is crucial, and it is why we use the field chosen.) For $$p^2+p+1=q+p+1$$ $$=1+1$$ $$=0.$$

We assign integer coordinates to the holes on the board, like this:
[image]

A situation is defined to be a set of pegs on the board. For any situation $S$ we define a value $A(S)=\sum p^{k+l}$ where the $\sum$ sign indicates that we add up all the $p^{k+l}$ for all the coordinates $(k,l)$ of pegs in the set S. (This, you may note, makes A a function with domain the set of possible situations and target the field with 4 elements). Thus for the situation (pegs marked in black)

[image]

S is the set ${(-2,-1),(-1,0),(0,0),(0,-1),(2,0),(1,2)}$ and we have $$A(S)=p^{-2-1}+p^{-1+0}+p^{0+0}+p^{0-1}+p^{2+0}+p^{1+2}$$ $$=p^{-3}+p^{-1}+p^0+p^{-1}+p^2+p^3$$ $$=1+q+1+q+q+1$$ $$=1+q$$ $$=p.$$

The function A is defined to have the very nice property: if a legal move changes situation $S$ into situation $T$, then $A(S)=A(T)$. The value of a situation is unchanged by legal moves, and therefore remains constant throughout the game.

**Question:**
Are there any games or examples that can familiarize us with 'ring of integers' and 'maximal ideal' or 'prime ideal'?

Comment: There is a huge disproportion, and a gap, between your motivating example and your actual question. "Ring theory" is a broad field. To me it is very unclear what you are looking for, and the motivating example, neat as it may be, does nothing to help.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you for your advice. I will edit my question

Comment: I don't understand your example entirely, I mean this is a rather strange question and is quite wonderful in that regard. So, let me just jump in and say to get a ring which is not a field you could seek a rule which gives a reducible polynomial like $p^2-2p+1 = (p-1)^2 = 0$ then when you quotient by the ideal generated by such you'll not get a field, but rather something with zero divisors which is just the direct product of the base ring up to a choice of notation I think. Great question. I have no idea.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thanks for your advice! But could you explain more precisely why did you choose reducible polynomial $p^2-2p+1 = (p-1)^2 =0$ ?

Comment: @pokssin no reason really, I suppose $p^2$ would also suffice, but generally anything of the form $(p-r_1)(p -r_2)$ where $r_1,r_2$ are in your base ring will suffice. If  $g(x) = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ then $R[x]/(g(x))$ isomorphic to $R \times R$. And $R \times \{0 \}$ and $\{ 0 \} \times R$ are all zero divisors in $R \times R$ hence it is most certainly not a field.